# ACPI on Asus NV56V Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: indicator, battery, acpi

i'm rather new to ubuntu and just made a fresh install of ubuntu 13.04 alongside windows 8 on my new asus N56V, however i couldn't make it shut down, reboot or logout properly which i taught was odd, so i googled abit and got the answer that i should turn off ACPI setting in grub (wrote acpi_osi in the linux quiet splash line)

this sort of solved my problem because with it turned off i can shut it down and log out from the computer properly as far as i can see.

However this made the battery indicator get all messed up

i wonder if there is any way to solve my problem without turning the acpi setting off, or to keep it off but have the battery indicator work as intended and not giving false data aswell as having the battery led notification on my laptop not blinking orange constantly as if the battery was low